# ReferenceError: ConferenceDataService is not defined for G Suite Calendar conferencing add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to play with the example at https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/calendar/calendar-actions#setting_conference_data_with_a_callback_function, and I am getting an error accessing some of the APIs.
Specifically, when I try to access the `ConferenceDataService` I get the error below.

```
ReferenceError: ConferenceDataService is not defined
```

I suspect there is a missing piece in the documentation for the G Suite Calendar conferencing add-ons.

There is also no information in the documentation about the "conferenceSolution" property in the manifest, which seems to be necessary in order to show up in the "Add Conferencing" drop down for a Google Calendar event.

Here is the manifest

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Calendar",
      "serviceId": "calendar",
      "version": "v3"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
   "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.read", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.current.event.write", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": ["https://companyxyz.com/"],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "companyxyz Test",
      "logoUrl": "https://companyxyz.com/logo32.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#6963ff",
        "secondaryColor": "#1f2933"
      },
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onHomepage",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "universalActions": [{
        "label": "Learn more about company xyz",
        "openLink": "https://companyxyz.com"
      }]
    },
    "calendar": {
      "conferenceSolution": [{
        "onCreateFunction": "createConference",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Company XYZ",
        "logoUrl": "https://companyxyz.com/images/logo192.png"
      }],
      "eventOpenTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "buildSimpleCard"
      },
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code.gs

```
function createConference(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  var dataBuilder = ConferenceDataService.newConferenceDataBuilder();
  return dataBuilder.build();  
}

function onHomepage(e) {
}

function buildSimpleCard(e) {
}
```

Calling `ConferenceDataService.newConferenceDataBuilder()` breaks immediately with the reference error mentioned above.

Comment: Please just paste that code into your question and any other relevent code as well.

Comment: As @Cooper has stated. We need more information about what are you trying to do. 
Maybe took a look at the documentation of the [service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/conference-data/conference-data-service). And there is in fact, information about [`conferenceSolution`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/conference-data/conference-data-builder#setconferencesolutionidconferencesolutionid)

Comment: Have you tried doing this with the previous runtime? Try disabling v8 and see if that works. Right now there could be still some problems with the `V8` runtime.

Comment: Same error from the https://console.cloud.google.com/logs
showing undefined ConferenceDataService in createConference function.
Turn off V8 to stable makes no difference.

Comment: I also cannot get that example to work, same error - "ReferenceError: ConferenceDataService is not defined" 
I am trying to write my own Conferencing AddOn and according to the Release Notes this should have been possible since Jan 2020 (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#january_2020)
I feel like there must be something missing in the project setup or manifest file, a missing dependency or something to do with publishing, but have not  been able to find anything in docs